# Checking for Guid Whitespace in FluentValidation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

```
public class GetCarQuery:IRequest<CartViewModel>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

 public GetCarIdValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id)
        .NotNull()
        .NotEmpty()
        .WithMessage("Id is not empty");
    }
```

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.BadHttpRequestException: Failed to bind parameter "Guid Id" from "   ".

When entering an empty value in the id of type guid, this error should appear : 'Id is not empty'

Comment: The error you see happens before the fluent validation, `" "` is not a valid value for `Guid`.

Comment: How do I check if the guid value is whitespace in fluent validation @GuruStron

Comment: In short - you can't. `Guid` can't have whitespace value since `Guid` is not a string.

Answer (score 2):

To check for an empty string doesnt make sence because the datatype of a Guid cannot be in this state. One could check for `Guid.Empty` which is

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Heres a method to check if a valid Guid was passed. I use it in some projects.

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, Guid> IsGuid<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, Guid> builder)
{
    return builder
        .Must(x => x != Guid.Empty);
}
```

usage:

```
 public class ModelAValidator : AbstractValidator<ModelA>
    {
        public ModelAValidator()
        {       
            RuleFor(x => x.MyProperty)
              .IsGuid()
              .WithMessage("The {PropertyName} has to be a valid guid.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `NotEmpty` checks for a `Guid` not being `Guid.Empty`.

Comment: @GuruStron thank you, I wasn't aware of that. I love to learn from the C# Guru.

Comment: =)) Check out the description in my profile (part about the name) =)

Answer (score 1):

`Guid` is not a string it can't have whitespace value (for example if you are posting JSON then the "problem" comes from JSON and .NET "type system", if the term is applicable to JSON, mismatch since JSON does not have concept of `Guid`, so to encode them JSON string values are used).

I would argue that if somebody passes something which could not be parsed as `Guid` the:

> Failed to bind parameter "Guid Id" from " "

error is perfectly fine.

If you want to handle the error via fluent validation then you will need to change the type of `Id` to `string`:

```
public class GetCarQuery:IRequest<CartViewModel>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

(adding something like `.Must(s => Guid.TryParse(s, out _))` also would be needed).

P.S.

1. `Guid` is not nullable (since it is a [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)), so either change property type to `Guid?` or you can safely remove the `NotNull` check
2. Seems that message should be `.WithMessage("Id is empty")` based on the text
3. The `NotEmpty` check actually validates that `Guid` is not `Guid.Empty`/`default` i.e. not `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. From [the docs](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html#notempty-validator):

   > **NotEmpty Validator**
   > Ensures that the specified property is not null, an empty string or whitespace (or the default value for value types, e.g., `0` for `int`). When used on an `IEnumerable` (such as arrays, collections, lists, etc.), the validator ensures that the `IEnumerable` is not empty.